# Sort an array of tuples by product in python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have an array of 3-tuples and I want to sort them in order of decreasing product of the elements of each tuple in Python. So, for example, given the array

> [(3,2,3), (2,2,2), (6,4,1)]

since 3*2*3 = 18, 2*2*2 = 8, 6*4*1 = 24, the final result would be

> [(6,4,1), (3,2,3), (2,2,2)]

I know how to sort by, for example, the first element of the tuple, but I'm not sure how to tackle this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `key` argument of [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sorted)/[`list.sort`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable) to specify a function for computing the product, and set the `reverse` argument to `True` to make the results descending rather than ascending, e.g.:

```
from operator import mul
print sorted([(3,2,3), (2,2,2), (6,4,1)], key=lambda tup: reduce(mul, tup), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Damn! you beat me by 15 seconds

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, I was just about to upvote you :p Since the question  explicitly says 3-tuples, I think the 3 parameter explicit version is clearer and more efficient.

Comment: You could also do `key=partial(reduce, mul)` with `partial` from `functools`.

Comment: @gnibbler: undeleted, only because you see value in the post :)

Answer (score 4):

```
In [176]: L = [(3,2,3), (2,2,2), (6,4,1)]

In [177]: L.sort(key=lambda (a,b,c):a*b*c, reverse=True)

In [178]: L
Out[178]: [(6, 4, 1), (3, 2, 3), (2, 2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 3):

A simpler solution from my point of view:

```
a = [(3,2,3), (2,2,2), (6,4,1)]

def f(L):
    return L[0]*L[1]*L[2]

print sorted(a, key = f, reverse = True)
```

**key** must be a function that returns a value that will be used in order to sort the list

**reverse** is True because you want it ordered in decreasing order

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from operator import mul
>>> input_list = [(3,2,3), (2,2,2), (6,4,1)]
>>> input_list.sort(key=lambda tup: reduce(mul,tup)) 
>>> print input_list
[(2, 2, 2), (3, 2, 3), (6, 4, 1)]
```